# Infinite loop - press any key to exit

Tags: loops, go, exit

I've infinite loop in my app and I need add one more functionality. Something like, "Press any key to exit...".

It's my code. Who knows the golden idea?

```
func main() {
   for {
      doAll()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

One option would be to start `doAll` in a goroutine and call fmt.Scanf:

```
func main() {
    go func() {
        for {
          doAll()
       }
    }()
    
    fmt.Println("Press any key to exit")
    var input string
    fmt.Scanf(input, "%s")
}
```